# Check if No checkbox checked before calling DestroyeAll Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

If no checkbox is selected an alert should be show **no Record Selected** if checkboxes checked it should then go to Controller otherwise just alert to checkbox before Delete
Here is my method

```
function delete () {
    if(confirm('Are you SURE!')) {
        var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "{{ url('/school/destroyAll') }}",
            data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'delete') {
                    window.location.href = "/school";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Just I want to add new Thing  here if no checkbox sleeted it should show an alert no should go on url*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  function delete () {
       if(!$('input:checkbox:checked').length){
           alert("No checkbox has selected");
           return false;
        }
       if(confirm('Are you SURE!')) {
           var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
           return this.value;
           }).get();
          $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "{{ url('/school/destroyAll') }}",
                data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                success: function(result) {
                                if(result == 'delete') {
                        window.location.href = "/school";
                    }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
function delete(){

if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length != 0){
            if(confirm('Are you SURE!')) {
        var checkedValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "{{ url('/school/destroyAll') }}",
        data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success: function(result) {
                        if(result == 'delete') {
                            window.location.href = "/school";
                        }
                    }
});
}else{
alert('no checkbox checked')
}

}
```

Comment: i am not clear how to use it in above method can you update your Question please